# How to align two videos from different angles of the same event

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I have two videos of the same event. You can see people walking, making the same moves, from a different angle. There is music playing.

Now I want to edit both videos in FCP 10.4.3 and fade from one video into the other. I'll use one audio track and mute the other. Video 2 starts later and ends earlier. Video 2 is layered upon (overlaps) video 1.

- Is there a way to move video 2 relative to video 1 with keys instead of the mouse? I need steps that are just 1 frame.
- Is there a way to see both layers at the same time, video 1 and video 2, to sync the steps?
- Is there a way to sync audio while keeping the video in sync with the audio? Like audio 1 in left ear, audio 2 in right ear or something like that?

Maybe there are excellent tutorials for this, but I'm probably using the wrong words for searching. I can't find them.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should try Multicam [Multicam workflow - Apple support](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12656?locale=en_US). 
The cut you make between both angles can be anything e.g. dissolve or blend.

To move clips with the keyboard you need to select it and type comma or full stop. [FCPX keyboard shortcuts - Apple support](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12724)

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on this as long as both files has reasonable audio of the same event you can sync by both files into a single Multicam clip using sync by audio.

Now when you can cut by switching angles

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12659?locale=en_AU&viewlocale=en_US

has more on sync by audio, alternatively search on youtube for a Multicam tutorial.